# Android studio pass data between tab fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments and one main activity(tabbed activity with two tabs). I will receive a string in fragment `f2`. Then if the user swipes the tab from `f2` to `f1`, `f1` should receive the string that is in `f2`.

I used a main activity to hold two fragments

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                F1 tab1 = new F1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                F2 tab2 = new F2();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

F1:

```
public class F1 extends Fragment {

TextView x;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
    x = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    return rootView;
}

}
```

F2:

```
public class F2 extends Fragment {

String x;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
    x = "myTest";
    return rootView;
}

}
```

So how can I pass the string `x` to `F1`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your viewPager pageListener and get your variable from fragment1 and pass it to fragment 2.

```
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {                
            tab2.setX(tab1.getX(););
        }
    });
```

Comment: I should add to my main activity?

Comment: Everywhere you instantiate your viewpager, usually your activity